# How to stop Java installer from "helpfully" offering to install toolbars, openoffice, etc. on every update

Tags: java, updates, installer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I permanently prevent Java security updates from installing Yahoo Toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/220897/can-i-permanently-prevent-java-security-updates-from-installing-yahoo-toolbar)

For a while now, every time I install an automatically-downloaded Java update, the installer offers me some junk I don't want (or at least don't want right then) in addition to the update, which defaults to "yes please install junk I don't want", so I have to be careful not to miss the checkbox before I reach the end of the installer or it actually *will* install whatever thing...

How can I make it stop doing this? In the answer to the question [Different installer variations of single Java version](/questions/162610/different-installer-variations-of-single-java-version), it says that installers with names like "jre-6u20-windows-i586-s.exe" offer the toolbars (implying that others don't), but I have no idea how to make the auto-updater download a type of installer that won't. Can it be done?

Comment: many applications distributed via the web offer to install extra bloat

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/629355/can-i-permanently-prevent-java-security-updates-from-installing-yahoo-toolbar

Comment: @Daisetsu: how does that count as a duplicate if it's on SO and this is SU?