# Can I permanently prevent Java security updates from installing Yahoo Toolbar?

Tags: java, security, software-bundling

Each time I get a Java security update, I have to remember to untick the box to install the yahoo toolbar browser plugin that they've decided, for some mad reason, is an important security feature of Java.  Is there a way to get it to remember my choice, or to get the security updates without it?  Or to educate Sun about what is and isn't a security update?

Comment: This is not really a programming-related question but I agree too much to close it.

Comment: Not only this, but once you perform a manual update, you must go back to the Java control panel and re-disable the "Check for updates automatically" option. It gets turned on with every update. I dislike Sun's practices with their updater very much.

Comment: If there's a command-line or console based update tool that might not have the Yahoo! Toolbar option, OR it might be much easier to bypass (such as with a script). However, I have no idea if there such a thing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two points...

If you do not want the added software you only have two options.

1. Continue to uncheck the box and keep your automatic updates.
2. Use the offline installer at java.sun.com. The offline installer has not added software. If you are industrious or know someone excellent with batch files you could write a script to check their ftp servers, compare file names, download a new one if present and then do a silent install.

That's about it...

I'd write the batch file for you but I really don't know how. ;)

Here is help with silent installs - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/silent.html

Answer (score 5):

Maybe block `toolbar.yahoo.com` at the router?

I had to come down to my father's house to unblock his email client after he hit the wrong option in a firewall requester after updating the email client.

When I checked the link in the email he was waiting for I noticed the Yahoo toolbar that Java had sneaked into an update.

After removing it using the add-on system in Firefox, I added `toolbar.yahoo.com` to the blocked list in the router, I guess I'll find out if it worked next time they push an update.

Answer (score 2):

I never install java...   I just copy it and manually set it to my classpath and other variables as needed to start the application.

Of course I do not get auto updates... then again.. maybe I do not want auto updates !  This ensures that I remain in control of my deployed environment and as a bonus...   My toolbars are free of yahoo junk !

then again... that does snot really answer the question though

Comment: That won't get you any browser plugin either, right? Of course, when not using the browser plugin, you're better of NOT installing it. But if installing it, then the automatic update is kind of a requirement nowadays, to ensure safe browsing.

Comment: Why oh why did this have to get voted so high when it even says that it doesn't actually answer the question...

Comment: Hmm, I guess not getting the browser plugins isn't really too relevant anymore, what with Oracle doing all they can to make theirs useless and all.

Answer (score 1):

I used this, don't know if it actually works, we'll see.

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/disable_offers.xml

How do I install Java without third party sponsor offers?

Releases of Java may provide a third party sponsor offer for users to install. If you wish to install Java without being presented any third party sponsor offers, there are a couple options.

Option 1: Disable sponsors through the Java Control Panel (Recommended method)
Option 2: Disable by installing Java through a specific Command Prompt method

Comment: "I used this, don't know if it actually works, we'll see." - before you post a possible solution you really should verify it works.  Perhaps you should stick to more current answers, so your not answering questions, based on stuff you "used to know"

Comment: Well, it worked for me. Haven't had problem anymore. Your mileage might vary, depending on your configuration, Java version etc. I did not test all possible (including future changes) combinations.

Comment: Plus my solution did not include phrase you made up "used to know". Don't know where that came from.

Comment: I quoted you, word for word, see the very first sentence in your answer........

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo! Toolbar is supposedly easy to uninstall : [How do I uninstall Yahoo! Toolbar?](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/toolbar/toolbar8/general/general-07.html).

Once uninstalled, I suggest changing Java automatic updates :
Control Panel -> Java -> Update tab -> Set Notify Me to "Before downloading", OK.

This will notify you when a update is available, and will let you manually update Java, thus getting the option of refusing the Yahoo! Toolbar.

It is a good idea to keep a visual control of what Java Update is doing. Since Sun was bought by Oracle, it is no longer trust-worthy, being much more marketing-oriented.

In general, one should keep all products up to date, not only Java. As most software products do not have automatic update, regularly running an update monitor such as [SUMo](http://www.kcsoftwares.com/?sumo) is recommended.

Comment: Will the industrious person distributing all these under-votes please justify himself?

Comment: I didn't vote, but this particular answer is recommending that you disable automatic updates for software that has had recent security vulnerabilities. That's a bad idea. It also doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TREE: I didn't take into account that most people don't use regularly an update monitor like I do, so I rewrote my answer. In any case, as most Java developers have left Sun, I still doubt the necessity of automatic update.

Comment: @harrymc: What is this "Sun" you speak of? (And where can I find it?)

Comment: @SamB: [Sun Microsystems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Microsystems) is the company that developed Java and many other open-source products. It is their owner. Unfortunately, it was recently bought by Oracle, which forced on it a profit-making culture that badly suited many developers in Sun, so they left.

Comment: @harrymc: sorry -- I was being facetious; I guess I need to figure out how to convey that more reliably in brief asynchronous messages. In other words, the point of my question was basically: "Gee, I sure wish Sun were still around."/"Are you implying that there are somehow still some Java developers working for Sun when you say 'most' of the developers have left Sun? If so, how can this be, when Sun no longer exists?"

Comment: Ha. Ha. The remaining Sun employees now have Oracle-appointed bosses. See [Oracle continues to make Sun customers miserable](http://www.infoworld.com/t/tech-support/oracle-continues-make-sun-customers-miserable-513?page=0,1&source=IFWNLE_nlt_daily_2011-01-17).

Comment: Who downvotes an answer from 2011?

Answer (score 0):

On the mac, there's a check-box at the bottom of the "Advanced" tab

https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/disable_offers.xml

Comment: This was already suggested years ago in another answer.