# How can I prevent Ask Toolbar and Ask Toolbar Updater from installing when jucheck installs an update?

Tags: security, java, automatic-update, software-bundling, jucheck

I know about [Can I permanently prevent Java security updates from installing Yahoo Toolbar?](https://superuser.com/questions/220897/can-i-permanently-prevent-java-security-updates-from-installing-yahoo-toolbar), but the accepted answer (use offline installer) keeps the Java auto-update (jucheck.exe) from downloading, and it makes it harder to update about a dozen PC's running various versions and editions of Windows.

So: is there a way to prevent the Ask Toolbar and Ask Toolbar Updater from installing when the Java Autoupdate (jucheck.exe) runs?

Comment: Did you uncheck the box that tells it to install? I haven't had this issue with jucheck.

Comment: @Ryan is right. If you don't install the toolbar during Java installation (just uncheck it) the auto updater should work fine. Maybe if you did not uncheck it it reinstalls during update even if you removed it manually. Also check out [this petition](https://www.change.org/petitions/oracle-corporation-stop-bundling-ask-toolbar-with-the-java-installer) ;-)

Comment: I'd love to see a solution that gets rid of the option entirely, though. Doubt it's possible but if it was it should be spread; tons of people just keep hitting "next" and wind up with half their screen full of toolbars.

Comment: @André I saw the petition (even signed it). Since it does not always install Ask Toolbar, the uncheck is easy to miss. See also the ZDnet link mentioned from the petition: http://www.zdnet.com/a-close-look-at-how-oracle-installs-deceptive-software-with-java-updates-7000010038/

Comment: A crazy idea here: Uninstall the toolbar. Create the default instalation folder manually and remove all write permissions. Not sure what will happen (or how this works under Windows) but it might be worth experimenting with.

Comment: Yes, easily. 

See this Q&A: http://superuser.com/questions/549028/how-can-i-prevent-ask-com-toolbar-from-being-installed-every-time-java-is-update

Comment: @abstrask thanks for that. Big relief that it is fixable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meant to put this as an answer, not a comment.

Yes, you can do that quickly and simple. See: [How can I prevent Ask.com Toolbar from being installed every time Java is updated?](https://superuser.com/questions/549028/how-can-i-prevent-ask-com-toolbar-from-being-installed-every-time-java-is-update)